# How can I make a weekly/recurring reminder via AppleScript?

Tags: applescript, reminders

Is there a way to access the recurring/repeating property of a reminder when making it in an AppleScript, like the following:

```
tell list chosenList
    make new reminder at end with properties {name:"Test", due date:date "6/9/2021 9:35 AM", repeat: weekly}
end tell
```

Where the part `repeat: weekly` won’t work …

Comment: RE: "Is there a way to access the recurring/repeating property of a reminder when making it in an AppleScript" --  If you look at the _properties_ listed for a `reminder` in the **AppleScript** dictionary for **Reminders** there is no _property_ for what's shown in the **UI** for **repeat:**, or if you query for the `properties` of a `reminder` there is no _property_ for it either. So it probably safe to say that as far as basic _vanilla_ **AppleScript** goes, the answer is no.

Comment: Thanks I saw that there’s no such thing in the property list. But do you know another way to set this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't look at all pretty, but it'd be worth testing to see if it works on current macOS...

https://macscripter.net/viewtopic.php?id=46061

Basically setting it with EventKit directly.

Comment: Thanks but this looks quite complicated (at least I didn’t understand what it down and how to apply it to my case …)

Comment: You asked how to make a recurring reminder.  That's how.  Or one way how.

Comment: Indeed, but I was hoping for a more robust and direct way way.